# Was this theme reviewed and made official by Ubuntu themselves?

Tags: 16.04, themes

I have installed a popular gtk theme called "Numix". It's pretty popular and has been reviewed by many different linux news teams. The recommended way to install it has been by adding their ppa. But when I went to their github page it had the option to install it by using the command: `sudo apt install numix-gtk-theme`.

https://github.com/numixproject/numix-gtk-theme

I didn't have to add a ppa. Does this mean that this theme is in the official repositories and has been reviewed by Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no additional apt repository needs to be added, then it means it is in the standard repository, yes.

On 16.04:

```
#: apt-cache policy numix-gtk-theme
numix-gtk-theme:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.1.2-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     2.1.2-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
```

However, this does not necessarily it has had any special review. It simply means that someone in Debian or Ubuntu volunteered to maintain a package in the archive. It will not necessarily be the latest version, depending on the version of Ubuntu you're using.